# Multiple/nested appllicationHost

Tags: durandal

Drupal's Nuget sample is turning out to be nice, and the docs helpful..

So far, figured out that `index.html` contains the host named as `applicationHost`:

```
  <div id="applicationHost"></div>
```

and was filled because `main.js` loaded the `shell.js` module:

```
router.mapNav('welcome');
...
app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');
```

that, upon view activation routed to the welcome `module`, therefore welcome `view`:

```
activate: function () {return router.activate('welcome');}
```

Great.

What I'm now trying to figure out is how to have nested 'applicationHost' containers, loading views into either one independendantly.

An example might be

```
router.mapNav('settings');
router.mapNav('settings/mailserver'); //but this one render within an inner container.
router.mapNav('settings/messages'); //but this one render within an inner container.
...
app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell', 'entrance');
```

So that `settings`.html is rendered, with *another container* within it and it's viewmodel some thing akin to:

```
//As restauants view comes in, it sets it's inner view to something
activate: function () {return router.activate('settings/mailserver');}
```

Related to this first question -- if there is a link on another page to `settings/messages`, or `settings/mailserver`, how do I ensure that the parent `settings` is ensured to be visible first?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You would like to use Visual Composition. 
e.g.

```
<div>
    <div data-bind="compose:'viewmodels/header'"></div>
</div>
```

Please refer:
http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition/

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for child routers http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router.html